# Замена цикла while

Tags: python, while, замена

Как можно заменить цикл while или такой код допустимый?

```
    self.count_rows = ceil(self.font.getsize(self.text)[0] / 500) # вычисляю количесто строк по ширине области
    self.list_text = self.text.split(' ') # создаю список из текста 
    self.text_in_rows = [''] * self.count_rows # список с текстом для каждой строки
    i = 0  
    while i < self.count_rows-1:
        for word in self.list_text:
            if self.font.getsize(self.text_in_rows[i] + word)[0] <= self.x_width:
                self.text_in_rows[i] += word + ' '
            else:
                i += 1
                self.text_in_rows[i] += word + ' '
```

UPD: Задача состоит в тот чтоб вставить в определенною область фотографии текст, который вписал пользователь. Я не знаю что делать с while, потому что если будет одна строка в цикл не зайдет. Мне лучше после цикла for добавить i += 1 или перед циклом while создать if для одной строки или вообще как можно избавиться от while?

Comment: Вы лучше напишите, какую задачу решаете. Так будет проще, чем восстанавливать задачу по вашему коду.

Comment: В любом случае копировать одни и те же строки, добавляя что-то в них - плохая затея. Лучше делать списки и потом их склеивать через `join`. А так вы копируете строку каждый раз, когда что-то в неё дописываете.

Comment: Мне после цикла for сделать список пустой и добавлять туда слова или я не правильно понял?

Comment: Я по коду всё-равно что-то не пойму. Вы один и тот же текст вставляете в много разных строк (обрезая его до слова по определённой ширине)?

Comment: Нет, в if self.font.getsize(self.text_in_rows[i] + word)[0] <= self.x_width я считаю сколько пунктов по координате х занимают слова, если меньше ширины самой рамки то я добавляю это слово в эту строчку, если нет, то я добавляю уже в следующею